# Program Error Subscript out of Range ... Tried On Error Resume

Tags: vba, excel

I am having problem with the subscript out of range with this line:

```
datasheet = wbook.Sheets("Month and Year")
```

I have tried to use `On Error Resume` but I might have done it wrong.

This code is suppose to establish month and year so that later, I am able to use it when I create a new sheet and refer to the previous one named similarly "Forecast *Month* *Year*". afterwards, it looks at 3 columns to validate that it is the row that it wants to copy and paste and then establishes it on the respective sheet.

```
Sub repeatingrows()

Dim wbook As Workbook
Set wbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

'CHECKS THE MONTH TO INCREASE THE YEAR
Dim datasheet As Worksheet
datasheet = wbook.Sheets("Month and Year")

Dim m As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim t As Integer

For t = 2 To 13
    For m = 1 To 13
        If m = 13 Then
            y = y + 1
            m = 1
        End If
    Next m
    m = .Cells(t, 1)
    .Cells(t, 1) = .Cells(t, 2)
Next t

'MAKE NEW SHEET AND RENAME IT

Dim oldsheet As Worksheet
Dim newsheet As Worksheet
Set oldsheet = Application.ActiveSheet

oldsheet = Sheets("Forecast " & m & " " & y)
newsheet = Sheets("Forecast " & (m + 1) & " " & y)

Sheets.Add.Name = "Forecast " & (m + 1) & " " & y



'CHECK IF the 3 columns ARE SIMILAIR TO PREVIOUS PAGE

Dim rrow As Integer

For rrow = 3 To 500
    If Sheets(3).Cell(rrow, 2) = Sheets(2).Cell(rrow, 2) Then
        If Sheets(3).Cell(rrow, 5) = Sheets(2).Cell(rrow, 5) Then
            If Sheets(3).Cell(rrow, 6) = Sheets(2).Cell(rrow, 6) Then
                With newsheet
                    oldsheet.Range(oldsheet.Cells(rrow, 16), oldsheet.Cells(rrow, 19)).Copy
                    .Range(.Cells(b, a), .Cells(99, 51)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
                End With '^COPY AND PASTES THE ROW
            Else
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Else
    End If
Next rrow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
Set datasheet = wbook.Sheets("Month and Year")
```

and check the spelling of the sheetname
and check that the sheet exists in the proper workbook.
and don't use **.Cells()** without a **With**

*(there may be other errors)*

Comment: I tried Set before but without wbook and then tried wbook without set. Of course, All i needed was both.

Comment: Actually, no it's still giving me the error. It was just  a more important error

Comment: @MaxAttack102 "Index out of range" means there's no sheet named `Month and Year` in the `Sheets` collection. Check the spelling - this answer is absolutely correct. Also note the `Set` keyword is **required** whenever you're assigning an object reference (as opposed to a *value*).

Comment: @Mat'sMug I have "Subscription out of Range".  Also, I just checked the spelling and it is spelled exactly as it says on the sheet.

Comment: @MaxAttack102 if that were the case then you wouldn't be having that error. Look for leading/trailing spaces, and make sure you're looking at the correct workbook.

Comment: OK, that was weird, I literallydid nothing except check the name of that sheet again and it worked. I mean I didn't even erase anything. Thank you @Mat'sMug